# Lock differences between Insert Into vs Select Into while using Openquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, locking, db2, linked-server

Using SQL Server 2014.  My DBA said I should be using `Insert Into` instead of `Select Into` when using `Openquery` because `Select Into` will create a lock on the linked server table. Is this true? linked server is DB2

What are the differences between the locks issued between these two queries?

```
select *
into local_table
from openquery(linked_server,'
select *
from schema.table
with ur');
```

---

```
insert into local_table
select *
from openquery(linked_server,'
select *
from schema.table
with ur');
```

**Edit:** I always specify `with ur` so I assumed the locks were the same, but my DBA says differently

Comment: no answers, just questions: 1) are you talking about a lock on the DB2 table or a lock on the SQL Server 'linked server table' (perhaps a stupid question) ? 2) what kind of lock is the DBA talking about ... shared? exclusive? something else?  3) what kind of locks have you (or the DBA) noticed while the query is actually running? [NOTE: I'd expect at least some sort of rolling shared lock on the source table, though that depends on the answer to the next question ...]; 4) what isolation level is in use in SQL Server and DB2?

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to go with `insert into table_name` instead of `select * into`, reason being I can define data type based on the column definition from source table instead of getting data type at run time based on data. Moreover select into will fail if there is already a table with that name and every time I need to specify new table or drop it prior to running this job. These issues won't be there in insert into.

Having said above, I couldn't find any difference in locking between these two process except table spool. I don't have DB2 database however I have one non-SQL database i.e. Sybase ASE and I tried the same thing there:

[image: Select * into Screen]

IO and Time statistics is as below:

[image: IO and Time Stats for Select * into]

Query execution plan is posted here --> https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkNyINCEI

Now, I performed insert into or the same set of tables:

[image: Insert into]

IO and time statistics is as below:

[image: IO and Time Stats for insert into]

Query plan is here for insert into --> https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJx5LEC4L

In my understanding - there is no difference in terms of locking however it has some performance difference.

I hope this helps you or at least you can test yourself for DB2 basis this answer.

Comment: While I don't see expressly listed in the plan (granted, not my area of greatest strength), I would expect that a select into from a remote server would first load the data into tempdb, the load into the final destination, whereas a insert into would bypass tempdb.  Right this second I don't have a test environment to confirm, however.